# How to query between two datetimes using Laravel and Eloquent but but datetimes are not ordered? (error Prepared statement contains too many place...)

Tags: laravel, datetime, eloquent, sql-order-by

Background:
Data is retrieved every minute from an API and stored in a 'sensors' table.
If the data is older than one year. They will be summarized, saved as one new entry in the database and the old data will be deleted. Therefore the column 'date' is not sorted. An update to a specific date is not possible, since I cannot be sure whether the sensor actually generated data at that time.

Now to my problem:
I have a querie that looks something like this

```php
private function getDataFromPeriod()
{
    return Sensor::whereBetween('date', [$this->start, $this->end])->orderBy('date')->get();
}
```

Where `$start` and `$end` are in this format for example: '2022-12-31 01:59:59'.

This function is called during the function `render()` and that works (at the beginning the data from the last year are sorted)). However, when I call this function repeatedly in a different place, the error `1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders` comes up.

I suspect this is because the query is not good.

Does anyone have an idea how I can improve the query or where else the error could be?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you are not sharing the piece of code that is actually breaking. The query you are providing is an ''as-is' query, and does not grow depending on conditions. It seems to me like you are running a loop that accumulates the sensor data, builds a new insert-statement, and this insert statement is what is growing to large. Mysql statements can only be x size, if you go over that, mysql will not execute it as it does not have enough memory to perform the operation. Usually you just need to chunk the operation into smaller chunks. If you can share more code, we might be able to help better

Comment: @Techno Thanks for the quick reply.

this function "getDataFromPeriod" is the only database query besides another function, but it doesn't cause any problem (fetches only the newest data from the database).

"getDataFromPeriod" is only called when rendering, i.e. at the beginning and afterwards when a "filter function" is called, which can set the values $start and $end. In both cases the output is stored in a new variable, which is then further used, e.g. display values in chartjs. But there is no database query done anymore. Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: I think there has to be, since you are getting the error `1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders` which is a mysql error.  You can try to use `DB::enableQueryLog();` before your query and `dump(DB::getQueryLog());` to see which queries are executed in a given section of code.  Maybe you have some events that are being triggered without your knowledge? Printing the querylog might provide valuable insight

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to sort by date;
just replace your code with this:

```
return Sensor::where('date','>=', $this->start)->where('date','<=', $this->end)->get();
```

this line will give you the sensors between your start and end date

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I don't think this will work in my case, because as already written above, I combine data older than one year and save it as a new entry in the database.
So the data will then somehow look like this:

------------------
'id' | 'name' | 'date' | ... 
1 | sensor1 | '2022-12-19 01:00:00' --------
2 | sensor1 | '2022-12-19 01:01:00' --------
3 | sensor1 | '2021-12-19 01:00:00'  <-- new date